# android java http timeout not working

Tags: java, android, http

How would I put a timeout into this in case the phone cannot contact the server?
The reason behind this is I have a loading dialog that keeps spinning and I would like the connection to just give up after 10 seconds which would shut the loading dialog off.

```
public class GetResults {
String data = null;
String URLME = null;
String Search = null;
BufferedReader inn;

@SuppressWarnings("finally")
public String GetLocationData(String THESEARCHSTRING) throws Exception {
    Search = THESEARCHSTRING;
    try {
        URL site = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
        java.net.URLConnection yc = site.openConnection();
        inn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String ln = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((l = inn.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(l + ln);
        }
        inn.close();

        data = sb.toString();
        URLME = data;
        return URLME;
    } finally {
        if (inn != null) {
            try {
                inn.close();
                return URLME;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return URLME;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: got it nvm yc.setConnectTimeout(5000);
   yc.setReadTimeout(10000);

Comment: It is entirely unreasonable to post a question entitled 'timeout not working' when you haven't even set one. -1

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use this and check do increasing timeout time.

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class c {
    static String data = null;
    static String URLME = null;
    static String Search = null;
    static BufferedReader inn;

```
@SuppressWarnings("finally")
public static String GetLocationData(String THESEARCHSTRING)
        throws Exception {
    Search = THESEARCHSTRING;
    try {
        URL site = new URL("http://www.google.com/");
        java.net.URLConnection yc = site.openConnection();
        yc.setConnectTimeout(1);
        inn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(yc.getInputStream()));
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer("");
        String l = "";
        String ln = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        while ((l = inn.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(l + ln);
        }
        inn.close();

        data = sb.toString();
        URLME = data;
        return URLME;
    } finally {
        if (inn != null) {
            try {
                inn.close();
                return URLME;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return URLME;
    }
}
```

}